# Проверка на дробность числа

Tags: java, числа

Не понимаю, как в данном коде сделать проверку на дробность числа.

Пробовал

```
if (x%1 !=0) и (x%2 ==1 && x%2 !=0)
```

и через `NumberFormat`.

Код:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class Loop1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Loop1 l1 = new Loop1();
        l1.scannerNumber();
    }
    public void scannerNumber() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число: ");
        long x = 0;
        long result = 1;
        int x1 = 0;
        int x2 = 0;
        while (x1 == 0 || x1 <0) {
            try {
                if (x2 == 5) {
                    System.out.println("Слишком много попыток. Программа закрывается");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                x = Long.parseLong(scan.nextLine());
                x1++;
                if (x<0) {
                    System.out.println("Вы ввели отрицательное число");
                    x1--;
                    x2++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Повтори попытку: ");
                x2++;
            }
        }
        if (x == 0) {
            System.out.println("Result = " + result);
            return;
        }
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                if (result < 0) {
                    System.out.println("У вас получилось переполнение " + result);
                    break;
                } else if (result > 0){
                    System.out.println("Result = " + result);
                    result *= (x - i);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что означает "Проверка на дробность"?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko Например если ввести 13.4 или другое дробное число(не важно через запятую или точку), чтобы в отдельном if я мог вывести сообщение о том, что введено дробное число. В данном случае когда я ввожу дробное число, то выводит, что я ввел строку(изначально так и планировалось). Теперь надо сделать проверку на дробность. Выше уже сказано, что я пробовал, не получается. Я понимаю, что через переменную double легко можно сделать, но мне надо именно long.

Comment: BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( "23452.4523434" );
BigDecimal fractionalPart = bd.remainder( BigDecimal.ONE );

достанет дробную часть. ПРоверить на ее отсутвие или наличие

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko Не пойму что за условие в if надо ввести с данным вариантом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - отбросить дробную часть (кастом к лонгу) и потом проверить, что разница между исходным числом и число, без дробной части больше 0

```java
double x = 3.14;
if (Math.abs((long) x - x) > 0) {
    System.out.println("число дробное");
} else {
    System.out.println("число целое");
}
```

пример выше скажет, что число 3.00 - целое (что, правильно)

Comment: `1e20` будет считаться дробным числом. :(

Answer (score 2):

[Math.rint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint-double-) возвращает ближайшее целое значение, но тип сохраняется `double`. Это позволяет избежать проблем с переполнением при приведении к целому типу больших значений:

```
    double x = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
    if (Math.rint(x) != x) {
        System.out.println("число дробное");
    } else {
        System.out.println("число целое");
    }
```

Другой способ - остаток от деления на единицу:

```
    double x = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
    if (x % 1 != 0) {
        System.out.println("число дробное");
    } else {
        System.out.println("число целое");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Double number = 3.14;
        if (number instanceof Double) {
            System.out.println("дробное");
        } else System.out.println("не дробное");

//
double d = 0;

        if (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
            d = scan.nextDouble();
```

**и при вводе с клавиатуры дробного числа, надо ставить запятую, а не точку.**

```
1,13
```

Comment: С Double понятно, а long или int можно как-нибудь на дробность проверить, значение которое вводится в Scanner.

Comment: странный вопрос. жаба строго типизированный язык нельзя присвоить double  в int и наоборот. единственное что можно, явное привидение `int x =(int)3.14;`

Comment: ты можешь предпологая что введётся дробное число, проверить наличие оного.... сейчас в ответ добавлю

Comment: С типом double мне понятно. Меня интересует как с типом long я могу проверить число. Меня не интересует тип double.

Comment: что значит проверить число?

Comment: long x3 = (long) x;
                if (x - x3 >0) {
                    System.out.println("Число дробное. Повторите попытку");
                    x1--;
                    x2++;
                } Ваш ответ помог. Я его чутка под себя сделал, но сама концепция помогла. Достаточно примитивный способ, но рабочий. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: это явное приведение, ты из double сделал long, отбросил дробную часть(потеря точности называется), было 3.14 стало 3 (т.е. было дробное, стало целочисленное)